# Rails, using rspec to run one file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I want to run an rspec test on one file.

I have tried various methods such as

```
rspec path/to/spec/file.rb
rake spec SPEC=spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb 
bundle exec rspec path/to/spec/file.rb
```

But all of them give me this error:

```
.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:146:in `to_app': missing run or map statement (RuntimeError)
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:160:in `block in generate_map'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:160:in `each'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:160:in `generate_map'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:145:in `to_app'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/rails.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
from /home/jay/Sites/New Folder/pg/scheduler/spec/spec_helper.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1455:in `require'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1455:in `block in requires='
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1455:in `each'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1455:in `requires='
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:112:in `block in process_options_into'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:111:in `each'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:111:in `process_options_into'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:99:in `setup'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
from /home/jay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<main>'
```

How do I run an rspec test on one file?

Comment: One of these should have worked. I myself use the first one. Must be something is broken either in your rspec setup or your app code.

Comment: First one should work. Can you please post the whole backtrace

Answer (score -2):

I tried :

```
ruby -I test test/unit/my_model_test.rb
```

and it worked for me let me know if it helped you

Comment: The question is about rspec.

Comment: Sorry does this : https://makandracards.com/makandra/47486-rspec-run-a-single-spec-example-or-examplegroup

help you more ?